# Is there a freely available source for VisiCalc documentation?

Tags: spreadsheet

I am looking for a freely available online document with instructions on how to use VisiCalc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VisiCalc Reference Card](http://www.danbricklin.com/history/refcard1.htm)

[Ref Card in PDF](http://www.scribd.com/doc/24693875/VisiCalc-Quick-Reference-Card)